# How to create a view-like pseudo table which points to different table if it's created

Tags: mysql, view, time-series, mariadb

I'm looking for a way to create a view-like pseudo table that is supposed to
indicate the newest table, specifically using MariaDB (if it's possible).

For example, there are a series of tables of the same schema.  But they contain
different data as time goes by.
In more detail, let's say series of fruit data.

fruit-jan-2021

```
| name | quality | price |
| ---- | ------- | ----- |
| apple | 4.5   | 1.1   |
| orange | 4    | 1.5  |
| peach | 3.5   | 1.7  |
```

friut-feb-2021

```
| name | quality | price |
| ---- | ------- | ----- |
| apple | 4.0   | 0.9   |
| orange | 5.0   | 1.8  |
| melon | 4.5   | 7.2  |
```

And the 'pseudo-table'(I'm not certain that it is a good expression... let's say `fruit-latest`) that I was looking for indicates the `fruit-feb-2021` if it's the latest among the tables that share the same schema.

Once the newer table(say, `fruit-aug-2021`) is created, my `fruit-latest` would automatically (if it's not possible then, manually) shift its point to the new one.

How can I do my best?

Comment: Instead, redesign the table to contain a date and store all this in one table

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you for your advice.  But I'm still a little afraid of the situation that it's accumulated almost permanently (actually I'm going to do it).  If then, the huge number of data in a single table wouldn't cause any performance issue despite I set some indexes?

Comment: mysql can handle hundreds of millions of rows in one table (on certain hardware). If you are afraid it is better to test with generated data in your specific environment.
I agree with RiggsFolly that using one table is more natural.
I worst case you could make some data migration (archiving) script to move data to archive table (or another database).

Comment: @petr OK. I accept your advice.  It explains and reasons clearer about using a single table for those data. Thank you! :)